# push to remote repo gives the error - there are still refs under

Tags: git

I am trying to push code to a remote repo -

```
git push uat release/1.1:release
Counting objects: 4047, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1679/1679), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4047/4047), 3.38 MiB | 1.79 MiB/s, done.
Total 4047 (delta 2160), reused 3666 (delta 1909)
remote: Switched to branch 'release'
To ubuntu@ubuntu-jvm:/repos/tms/uat
 * [new branch]      release/1.1 -> release
error: there are still refs under 'refs/remotes/uat/release'
error: Cannot lock the ref 'refs/remotes/uat/release'.
```

How do I resolve the above error.

Comment: You wouldn't have a tag colliding with a directory name, by any chance? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9335269/6309)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you have other branches named `release/<something>` on your `uat` remote. The `push` command you are running is trying to convert a local branch `release/1.1` into a remote branch `release`, but the remote refuses to remove `release/<something>` because that would lose information. Try `git push uat release/1.1:newrelease` or something similar to avoid the conflict of trying to have a single branch named the same thing as a "subdirectory" containing other branches (it's not truly a subdirectory, but the way `git` works internally, it is sometimes stored as an actual subdirectory).

`git remote show uat` or `git branch -r` will show you what branches your `uat` remote has.